# Stopping services remotely with a local user admin

Tags: service

I am trying to stop and start services remotely using the username and password of a local user that is a admin on the machine on which the services run.

```
sc \\remotePC start someService username someUser password somePassword
```

doesn't seem to work, but when I try it with a domain user that has admin rights, it works fine.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You use command "... username remotePCname\someUser ...", right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing <kbd>username</kbd> to <kbd>machine_name\username</kbd> - eg. pc999\joe_bloggs

Comment: Yep, that's it. I feel pretty silly right now. Thanks alot!!